# Progress on the result about montonicity of Kazhdan Lustzig polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, coxeter-groups, kazhdan-lusztig

I am reading the paper [**Masato Kobayashi---Combinatorics on Bruhat Graphs and
Kazhdan-Lusztig Polynomials**.](http://www.m-hikari.com/pms/pms-2014/pms-1-4-2014/kobayashiPMS1-4-2014.pdf)

Let $P_{x,w}$ be the Kazhdan Lusztig polynomial of $W$.
There is a result about crystallographic Coxeter group $W$: 
[image]

> I would like to know whether there is any generalization of this result to a larger class of Coxeter groups which has been proven up to now?

Comment: Keep in mind the fact that the known result aready covers all cases in which the group is a "Weyl group", though your question is a natural one to raise. (By the way, I just expanded the tags and fixed a couple of small linguistic errors.)